# Is it possible to have local states in container?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is the full [code](https://github.com/kenpeter/test_container).

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './containers/Home';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <Home />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

src/containers/Home/Home.js

```
// react
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
// css
import './Home.css';

// after the map, can get from props
const Home = (props) => {

    console.log('-- home --');
    console.log(props);

    return (
      <div>
          <h3>output: {props.homeClick}</h3>
          <div className="Home">Home</div>
          <button onClick={() => {props.homeClickAction(1)}}>test click</button>
      </div>
    );
};

// attr
Home.propTypes = {

};

export default Home;
```

One of the file: src/containers/Home/Home.container.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {homeClickAction} from './home.action';
import Home from './Home';

// NOTE: for state.reducer.var
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        homeClick: state.homeReducer.homeClick
    }
}

// const var
// dispatch
// return
// key
// data => { fire(actionCreator(data)) }
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        homeClickAction: data => {
            dispatch(homeClickAction(data))
        }
    }
}

const HomeContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Home);

export default HomeContainer;
```

Is it possible to have internal state like `loading: true`, without going through redux?

Comment: Of course you can, just read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: The idea is to write a class instead of a function.

Comment: @MarsonMao, I know how to write a class, but how can you write one combining mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, in the container. Are you able to transform the code above.

Comment: Yes, you can. Wouldn't make much sense since though. You should keep your 'local states' on the component

Comment: @kivul, if I add local state to component (not container), the component is no longer dummy component. I want to have state, logic in container and render only in component. not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to explain, I'll just paste the codes here, but it's really intuitive, I think you must have been stuck on something tiny so you can't figure it out.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {homeClickAction} from './home.action';
import Home from './Home';

class HomeCombined extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    loading: false,
  };

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;
    const { homeClick, homeClickAction } = this.props;
    return (
      loading ? <div>loading...</div> : <Home />
    );
  }
}

// NOTE: for state.reducer.var
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        homeClick: state.homeReducer.homeClick
    }
}

// const var
// dispatch
// return
// key
// data => { fire(actionCreator(data)) }
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        homeClickAction: data => {
            dispatch(homeClickAction(data))
        }
    }
}

const HomeContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeCombined);

export default HomeContainer;
```